# How to auto save on *.coffee files when lose focus (in insert mode) then also back to normal mode

Tags: vimrc, gvim, vim-windows

I'd like to lose focus when I'm in insert mode, to trigger auto-save on *.coffee buffers and also I need it to change mode from insert to normal mode to trigger Live compile feature of vim-coffee-script plguin.

What I achieved now:
`autocmd BufWritePost,FocusLost *.coffee  :wa`

But how to bring it to normal mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As my understanding, if I have this in vimrc: `autocmd BufWritePost *    :<ESC>
`. It won't work because user needs to switch to normal mode first before be able to do the command `<ES>`. I'm trying to put two commands in a function.

Comment: Remove the leading colon on `:<Esc>`—does that work?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: I'll check it on next monday. Actually we can run multiple commands like so: `autocmd FocusLost *.coffee  :wa | stopinsert`. But from what I've tested I have to move to another buffer in the same window (`buffer1 | buffer2`) to trigger normal mode in that buffer then go back to `.coffee` to get normal, idk why. I set `mousefocus` to do what I've mentioned.

Comment: I guess I’m just confused as to why that seems necessary to get from insert to normal. It should be as simple as an Esc. *shrugs* not sure

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: I used vim-coffee-script plugin with auto-save autocmd as mentioned above and for unknown reason the feature `live preview compiling` - CoffeeWatch can only be triggered when .coffee saved and buffer in normal mode or just normal mode. auto-save on first post will run in background and keep buffer in insert mode. For quick testing purpose I need to paste and back to another app.